# Executing script on files and saving modifications with the same file names

Tags: bash, save

I have this script in bash that want to execute it on different text files and then save this modifications on the files with the same name.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{if (d) d=d RS $0; else d=$0}
/>/{s++;next}
s==1 && /[ACGT]/{gsub(/[^ACGT]+/, ""); n+=length($0)} 
END{print s, n, "1" RS d}' < mytextfiles_*.txt > mytexfiles_withmodifications_*.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, but backup first!

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.txt
do
    echo Processing ${i}
    awk .... "${i}" > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp "${i}"
done
```

You may want to select other than "*.txt". Put your own awk stuff in where I have "..."

Explanation:
It loops through all the "txt" files in your current directory. It runs your awk command on each one and saves the output in a temporary file (name formed using ProcessId.tmp). If the awk is successful, it renames the temporary file the same as the original - thereby overwriting it. Note that permissions will not be preserved.

Comment: I tried it but got this error ./header.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
./header.sh: line 5: ` echo Processing ${i}'

Comment: Here is the script in http://pastebin.com/PyfMmmG2 for you to check. Thanks again!

Comment: If you run "which bash" does it say "/bin/bash"? If not, change the first line to match what it says. Did you put your awk script in where I put "..."

Comment: Yes, it says /bin/bash

Comment: OMG yes! I missed it too. Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent! Sorry it took me so long :-)